# MongoDB - Difference between index on text field and text index?

Tags: mongodb, text, indexing

For a MongoDB field that contains strings (for example, state or province names), what (if any) difference is there between creating an index on a string-type field :

```
db.ensureIndex( { field: 1 } )
```

and creating a text index on that field:

```
db.ensureIndex( { field: "text" }
```

Where, in both cases, `field` is of `string` type.

I'm looking for a way to do a case-insensitive search on a text field which would contain a single word (maybe more). Being new to Mongo, I'm having trouble distinguishing between using the above two index methods, and even something like a `$regex` search.

Comment: Drilled down to 1 line: One powers an FTS tech and the other is a normal index for a find query.

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet, but [case insensitive indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive) seem to be the solution you're looking for!  I wanted to mention it now, in case I forget to come back and write up an answer.

Comment: Case-insensitive indexes are new in mongodb 3.4 (which I am not using, unfortunately).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The two index options are very different.

- When you create a regular index on a string field it indexes the
  entire value in the string. Mostly useful for single word strings
  (like a username for logins) where you can match exactly.
- A text index on the other hand will tokenize and stem the content of
  the field. So it will break the string into individual words or
  tokens, and will further reduce them to their stems so that variants
  of the same word will match ("talk" matching "talks", "talked" and
  "talking" for example, as "talk" is a stem of all three). Mostly
  useful for true text (sentences, paragraphs, etc).

  > **Text Search**
  >
  > Text search supports the search of string content in documents of a
  >   collection. MongoDB provides the `$text` operator to perform text search
  >   in queries and in aggregation pipelines.
  >
  > The text search process:
  >
  > ```
  > tokenizes and stems the search term(s) during both the index creation and the text command execution.
  > assigns a score to each document that contains the search term in the indexed fields. The score determines the relevance of a document to a given search query.
  > ```
  >
  > The `$text` operator can search for words and phrases. The query matches
  >   on the complete stemmed words. For example, if a document field
  >   contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match
  >   the document. However, a search on either blueberry or blueberries
  >   will match.
- `$regex` searches can be used with regular indexes on string fields, to
  provide some pattern matching and wildcard search. Not a terribly
  effective user of indexes but it will use indexes where it can:

  > If an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular
  >   expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a
  >   collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular
  >   expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential
  >   matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a
  >   “range” from that prefix and only match against those values from the
  >   index that fall within that range.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: This is nice and clear, thank you! What would be the best approach for doing a case-insensitive search on a field which contains a single word? It sounds like both `$regex` or a text index would work. Does a `$regex` search make use of the regular index at all?

Comment: According to [the mongodb regex documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) linked above: _For case insensitive regular expression queries, these queries generally cannot use indexes effectively._

Comment: Hi, I would like to have a question about these 2 types of above indexes. Which one should I use when there are 2 queries, 1 that = name and the other is following regex on the username?

Answer (score 14):

**text indexes** allow you to search for words inside texts. You can do the same using a regex on a non text-indexed text field, but it would be much slower.

Prior to MongoDB 2.6, text search operations had to be made with their own command, which was a big drawback because you coulnd't combine it with other filters, nor treat the result as a common cursor. As of now, the text search is just another another operator for the typical `find` method and that's super nice.

So, Why is a text index, and its subsequent searchs faster than a regex on a non-indexed text field? It's because text indexes work as a dictionary, a clever one that's capable of discarding words on a per-language basis (defaults to english). When you run a text search query, you run it against the dictionary, saving yourself the time that would otherwise be spent iterating over the whole collection.

Keep in mind that the text index will grow along with your collection, and it can use a lot of space. I learnt this the hard way when using capped collections. There's no way to cap text indexes.

A **regular index** on a text field, such as

```
db.ensureIndex( { field: 1 } )
```

will be useful only if you search for the whole text. It's used for example to look for alphanumeric hashes. It doesn't make any sense to apply this kind of indexes when storing text paragraphs, phrases, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response! You mentioned that a text index is faster than a regex on non-indexed text field. What about a regex on a (normal) indexed text field (containing only 1 word)? Would there be any benefit to adding a text-index to a field containing only 1 word (for exact, case-insensitive matching)?

Comment: for exact matching, either case sensitive or insensitive, there's no use of text indexes. But for that matter, you don't need to use regex either. Keep in mind that text indexes keep a dictionary of words (exploding the text by spaces and discarding common words and special chars), while regex matches substring patterns that can include spaces, quotes, colons, etc.

Comment: Hmm okay, so how would I perform case-insensitive exact matching without using regex on a normal-indexed text field? Won't the hash created by the normal index be affected by the casing?

Comment: @russdot Did you find an answer to this?  According to the [regex documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), _For case insensitive regular expression queries, these queries generally cannot use indexes effectively_.  Not sure how you would do it without regex or a text index.

Comment: I finally stumbled across [case insensitive indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive)!  Everyone keeps typing about text indexes, so it was hard to find...

Comment: @NealGokli Sadly, I don't remember if I ever came up with a solution. But MongoDB has gone through many updates since I originally posted the question, so thanks for providing more follow up info!