# Does mongodb support regex in values of text indexes

Tags: regex, mongodb, mlab

I want to create a text index by using regex, not using exact values, does mongodb supports this.

Ex: db.telemetry_series.createIndex( { key: "^SimulcastStatCounterManager\.Client-" } )

Answer (score 0):

Yes MongoDB supports regex with text index, Please check the below link its same as your question.
[MongoDB - Difference between index on text field and text index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316117/mongodb-difference-between-index-on-text-field-and-text-index)