# MongoDB: Indexing for a live search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

### Situation

I need to create a live search with MongoDB. But I don't know, which index is better to use [normal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/) or [text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/). Yesterday I found [main differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316117/mongodb-difference-between-index-on-text-field-and-text-index) between them. I have a following document:

```
{
    title: 'What vitamins are found in blueberries'
    //other fields
}
```

So, when user enter **blue**, the system must find this document (... **blue**berries).

### Problem

I found these differences in the article about them:

> A text index on the other hard will tokenize and stem the content of the field. So it will break the string into individual words or tokens, and will further reduce them to their stems so that variants of the same word will match ("talk" matching "talks", "talked" and "talking" for example, as "talk" is a stem of all three).

> So, Why is a text index, and its subsequent searchs faster than a regex on a non-indexed text field? It's because text indexes work as a dictionary, a clever one that's capable of discarding words on a per-language basis (defaults to english). When you run a text search query, you run it against the dictionary, saving yourself the time that would otherwise be spent iterating over the whole collection.

That's what I need, but:

> The $text operator can search for words and phrases. The query matches on the complete stemmed words. For example, if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match the document. However, a search on either blueberry or blueberries will match.

### Question

I need a fast clever dictionary but I also need searching by substring. How can I join these two methods?

Comment: Not really. A "text search" is a "text search", and therefore primarily concerned with "real words" and not partials or "stop words". If you want to do the latter then you use [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), which is of course not the best performance unless matching always from the beginning of a "string". The reason you cannot "combine" is that the `$text` search needs to be the first match condition. So the "not real words" would be excluded from the results.