# MongoDb Indexing full text search

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I have a document named "posts", it is like this :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afc22290c06a67f081fa463"), 
    "title" : "Cool", 
    "description" : "this is amazing" 
}
```

And I have putted index on title and description :

```
db.posts.createIndex( { title: "text", description: "text" } )
```

The problem is when I search and type for example "amaz" it return the data with "this is amazing" above, while it should return data only when I type "amazing"

```
 db.posts.find({ $text: { $search: 'amaz' } }, (err, results) => {
     return res.json(results); 
  });
```

Comment: Isn't that how full text index searching is designed to work? Honest question. I'm not that familiar with MongoDB.

Comment: Normally, it should search word. Because I've tried to update the description text by "this is amazing legend game". When I type "legen", he didn't found nothing or if I type "legend" it work.

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316510/7948962) MongoDB tokenizes words in the text index, so `amaz` looks like it is a token of `amazing` as `talk` would be to `talking`. (I'm pretty sure this is working as intended and you just found an odd token case)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a good explanation. You saved me, because I didn't understand what's going on before. God bless you

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. I will put up an answer in case future users find this helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @amenadiel for the original data here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316510/7948962

From the MongoDB docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

> ## Index Entries
>
> text index tokenizes and stems the terms in the indexed fields for the index entries. text index stores one index entry for each unique stemmed term in each indexed field for each document in the collection. The index uses simple language-specific suffix stemming.

This is to allow you to search partial "stem" terms in the index, and have the database return all related results. In your specific scenario, `amaz` is a bit of an odd token as it is a bit irregular compared to other words such as `talking`, which is tokenized to the word `talk`, or `talked` to `talk`. Similarly `walking` and `walked` to `walk`.

In your case, the word `amazing` in your text will be tokenized as `amaz`. If your column contained data such as `amazed`, it would receive the same `amaz` token as well. And those results would also be returned from a search of `amaz`.